# Python type hinting: custom data type

Tags: python, typing

Let say, I want to have a custom type that I call `Size`.
Fundamentally, this type is nothing more than an int.

However, I would like to have the following behaviour:

```
some_size: Size = 42
not_a_size: int = 12

>>> isinstance(some_size, int)
True

>>> isinstance(some_size, Size)
True

>>> isinstance(not_a_size, int)
True

>>> isinstance(not_a_size, Size)
False
```

Defining a type alias: `Size = int` is possible, but `isinstance(not_a_size, Size)` would return `True`.
I also explored `TypeVar` (`Size = TypeVar('Size', bound=int)`) but it is not made for this.

Comment: Note that the `Size` in `some_size: Size = 42` is just a type *annotation*. It has absolutely no effect on the runtime behaviour/value of `some_size` or `42`, including `isinstance` checks.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson The general idea of subclassing was fine, but done poorly – `int` is an immutable representation of its value, by creating a subclass without `__slots__` and assigning the value to a field your class was mutable and contained its value twice. Either way, it would not have satisfied the requirements in the question since that's just not possible to do.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ahh, I see. I have updated my answer after doing a bit of research into your comment (thank you very much by the way, I would have been forever lost without it). I'm still slightly confused as to why you believe the above functionality cannot be achieved?

Comment: @ChaddRobertson Because `some_size: Size = 42` is completely equivalent to `some_size = 42`. The variable contains a plain integer, not a `Size` value. Annotations do not have a runtime effect unless some code explicitly processes them (such as `functools.singledispatch` or `dataclasses.dataclass`). If you check your own code, `isinstance(some_size, Size)` will be `False`.